# Efficiently augment a data frame by values found in a matrix

Tags: r, performance, matrix, dataframe

I have the following data frame (called `cp`):

```
   v1 v2 v3 v4  
1   1  2  3  4  
2   3  1  2  4  
3   4  2  1  3
```

Where 1, 2, 3 and 4 are nodes on a directed graph. The distance between the nodes is given by the following weighted adjacency matrix (let's call it `B`):

```
0  3  1  2
3  0  1  4
1  1  0  2
2  4  2  0
```

I need to augment the columns in the data frame with the distance between the nodes given by the rows and columns of the adjacency matrix (again data frame `cp`):

```
   v1 v2 v3 v4 V5 V6 V7  
1   1  2  3  4  3  1  2
2   3  1  2  4  1  3  4
3   4  2  1  3  4  3  1
```

That is, the values on columns `V5, V6 and V7` come from looking up the distance between the adjacent pairs of nodes in colunms `v1` to `v4`.  For example, the 3 in column `V5` is the distance from node 1 and 2 -which is found in the first row and second column of matrix `B` (that is, 3), and so on.

I have written the following code in R to achieve this:

```
for (i in 1:3){
for (j in 5:7){
cp[i, j] <- B[cp[i, j - 4], cp[i, j - 3]]
}
}
```

The code works fine with a data frame of just a few observations.  The problem is that it takes many many hours to process a data frame of 9 columns and 11 million observations.  Can you please help me find a more efficient way to do this without the for loops?

Comment: V5 and V6 do not make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, matrices are stored in a one dimensional vector. You can make use of this and index pairs of indices in a matrix using this property.

Hence you can do this:

```
B <- as.matrix(B)
cp <- cbind(cp, sapply(1:(ncol(cp) - 1), function(ii){          
            B[cp[,ii] + nrow(B) * (cp[,ii+1] - 1)]          
        })) 

cp
#   v1 v2 v3 v4 1 2 3
# 1  1  2  3  4 3 1 2
# 2  3  1  2  4 1 3 4
# 3  4  2  1  3 4 3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this which should be way faster as your data frame `cp` has 9 columns:

```
res <- apply(mapply(seq, seq(ncol(cp)-1), 2:ncol(cp)), 2, function(i) B[cp[,i]])

#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    1    2
#[2,]    1    3    4
#[3,]    4    3    1
```

`cbind(cp, res)` will give your desired output.

You can convert your data frame `cp` to a matrix by `as.matrix(cp)`. The type matrix is used here because of easier vectorization.

---

**Benchmarking** (`cp` of dim `1e+6 x 9`)

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1)
cp <- t(replicate(1e+6, sample(9)))
B <- t(replicate(9, sample(9)-1))

f989=function() apply(mapply(seq, seq(ncol(cp)-1), 2:ncol(cp)), 2, function(i) B[cp[,i]])
fikop=function() sapply(1:(ncol(cp) - 1), function(ii){          
            B[cp[,ii] + nrow(B) * (cp[,ii+1] - 1)]          
        })

all(f989()==fikop())
# [1] TRUE  
microbenchmark(f989(), fikop())

# Unit: milliseconds
    # expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
  # f989() 157.4025 165.0029 190.5306 200.8816 204.6907 239.720   100
 # fikop() 212.2289 255.1914 259.2568 261.1330 266.3382 310.974   100
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very helpful.